# Reshape/Transpose duplicated rows to column in R studio

Tags: r, replace, reshape, transpose

I have data that looks like this:

| ID | Name | Adress | Score | Requirement | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | CA | 1 | Internet | OK |
| 1 | John | CA | 1 | TV | Not OK |
| 1 | John | CA | 1 | Household | OK |
| 2 | Ann | LA | 3 | Internet | Not OK |
| 2 | Ann | LA | 3 | TV | Follow up |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The ID is unique for each "customer", and from row 1-3 columns ID, Name, Adress and Score is the same. There are 3 requirements for each customer and I want to transform the 3 requirements as columns with the status as values, so that it deletes duplicates. As follows:

| ID | Name | Adress | Score | Internet | TV | Household |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | CA | 1 | OK | Not OK | OK |
| 2 | Ann | LA | 3 | Not OK | Follow up | OK |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have tried to search for previous cases with reshape and dcast in R studio, but have not found similar to mine.
Can someone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pivot_wider from tidyr package

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# your data
df <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Name, ~Adress, ~Score, ~Requirement, ~Status,
  1, "John", "CA", 1, "Internet", "OK", 
  1, "John", "CA", 1, "TV", "Not OK", 
  1, "John", "CA", 1, "Household", "OK", 
  2, "Ann", "LA", 3, "Internet", "Not OK", 
  2, "Ann", "LA", 3, "TV", "Follow up")


df <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Requirement, values_from = Status)
```